# What are the key differences between the res folder and the arsc file in a built apk?

Tags: android

When I build an apk, for example building a blank Android Studio - Phone and Tablet/Basic Activity project, and open said apk as a zip I see several things there. I understand what is what, and I always thought that aapt creates the arsc file, which contains the resources converted to a better optimized binary format, which still seems valid... However what I don't entirely understand that what goes into the res folder within the apk.

[image: insides of an apk]

My intuition tells me that only the publicly accessible resources stay in the res folder, and anything that is only used "internally" goes into the arsc file. (for example I'd expect the exported="true" activity's layout to go into the res folder) However I haven't really found any confirmation of this.

Can someone please tell me which resource goes where exactly, and are they possibly duplicated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`aapt` does three things with the `res` directory.

Based on the whole directory it generates the `R.java` source file which contains a mapping of each resource item to an individual ID. These resource IDs will be used by the appication during runtime to access the resources. `R.java` is included into the Java/Kotlin compilation process.

The `res/value` subdirectory -- which contains values for strings, styles, colors and further (see [Android Development Documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#table1)) -- is compiled into the `resources.arsc` file. That is basically a table for such kind of values, making it more effective to access them during runtime.

Finally the `res` directory -- but without `res/value`, whose content is now to be found in `resources.arsc`, so there is no duplication -- is packed as-is into the APK file.

More about APK structure and build process can be found on the [Mobile Development Site](https://timeout.userpage.fu-berlin.de/apk-building-on-mobile) by Michael Zent.

Comment: Thanks, I've eventually ended up learning the hard way and building my own arsc parser.